# SAS Pass Through OpenQuery into iHistorian Error

Tags: sql, sas, interactive, pass-through

I am doing a pass through query using SAS into iHistorian Interactive SQL. The code is listed below. I know the pass through code works; I ran the quoted code through iHistorian Interactive SQL itself and it returned the required data. I get the following error when I attempt the provided code.

ERROR: CLI describe error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB
provider "IhOLEDB.iHistorian" for linked server "fsp1".

Has anyone tried this with iHistorian? Does anyone know what's going on here? Thanks in advance.

---

```
proc sql;

connect to odbc as conn(dsn="FSPPDW" uid=FontaneF);
create table work.Stuff as
select * from connection to conn (
select * from OPENQUERY(fsp1,

'SELECT
tagname,
timestamp,
value as Signal

FROM ihrawdata
WHERE timestamp > 10/23/2015 AND timestamp < 10/25/2015
AND (tagname = Fsdfeee:000)
AND intervalmilliseconds = 60000
AND samplingmode=interpolated'
)    
);
disconnect from conn;
;
quit;
```

Comment: Your date constants are missing single quotes.  That would appear to be at least one problem.  I would also suggest using ISO standard date format, YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Further to the single quotes, if iHistorian is like sql-server, you'll have to quote the quotes.  Also, there are two text fields with the same issue.